# React web - vaciar opciones de check cuando se vuelve a ocultar checks dependientes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando react web y tengo un grupo de checks. Vamos a llamarlo grupocheck1 que tiene opcion1, opcion2 y opcion3. Si marco opcion1 me habilita un grupo check (grupocheck2) que estaba oculto. Y me da opciones opcion4, opcion5 y opcion6. El funcionamiento es el correcto. 
Ahora desmarco la opcion1 del grupocheck1 y me desaparece el grupocheck 2 con sus opciones (opcion4, opcion5 y opcion6).

Si vuelvo a marcar  el grupocheck1 con la opcion1, me vuelve aparecer el grupocheck2 pero con la opcion4 que había marcado anteriormente. Quisiera que este desmarcado, porque se había ocultado la opcion1 que ocultaba el grupocheck2. No estoy usando state. Como podría hacer para solucionar el problema. Con handlers o como?

Una parte del codigo porque es muy largo:

```
<CheckboxGroupInput
    source="tortureType"
    choices={[
        {
            id: "Físicamente",
            name: "Físicamente"
        },
        {
            id: "Psicológicamente",
            name: "Psicológicamente"
        },
        {
            id: "Sexualmente",
            name: "Sexualmente"
        }
    ]}
    options={{ labelposition: "left" }}
    //onChange={handleChange}
    //onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
/>

<FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData, ...rest }) =>
        formData.tortureType &&
          formData.tortureType.includes("Físicamente") && (
            <CheckboxGroupInput
                source="tortureTypePhy"
                choices={[
                    {
                        id: "Estirones",
                        name: "Estirones"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "Arrojaron objetos",
                        name: "Arrojaron objetos"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "Bolsa en la cabeza",
                        name: "Bolsa en la cabeza"
                    }
                ]}
                options={{ labelposition: "left" }}
                {...rest}
            />
           )
       }
</FormDataConsumer>
```

Utilizo react admin

Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo puedes solucionar reseteando el contenido de `grupocheck2` cada vez que se oculte `grupocheck1`, bien recorriendo uno por uno o como lo estés manejando

Comment: si. pero como? me podrías dar un código o link. Gracias

Comment: Si, comparte el código que llevas avanzado y sobre el te pongo el ejemplo encantado.

Comment: Agregue el código. Avisame si necesitas algo mas. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si, yo usaría handlers para el estado de los grupos de checks, te pongo un ejemplo.

Si estás usando React mi opción preferida sería el state del componente que tiene la lógica de los grupos de checks.

```
class MyClassContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    grupoActivo: 1,
  };

  setGrupoActivo = (grupoActivo) => { // 1,2,3...
    this.setState({ grupoActivo })
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.grupoActivo === 1) {
      return // aqui muestras el grupo 1...
    }
    if (this.state.grupoActivo === 2) {
      return // aqui muestras el grupo 2...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

en los checks recuerda llamar al método `setGrupoActivo` pasándole como parámetro el id del grupo siguiente.

Esta sería una forma, según escribía el ejemplo se me ha ocurrido alguna otra así que, si te parece, prueba algo así y si no te funciona lo vemos.

Comment: Y donde coloco que se resetee los valores del grupo 2?

Comment: para resetear los valores del grupo 2 puedes crear otro método parecido a `setGrupoActivo` (`resetGrupo`) y en él resetear los items que necesites en base al grupo que le pases como parámetro,